# Extending a default schema in OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

I'm trying to extend the inetorgperson schema with a date attribute in OpenLDAP 2.4.X.Which is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Create an auxiliary class with the attribute and mix it into your objects.  You really shouldn't touch the core schemas.