# How to extend OpenLDAP person class

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I'm looking for any way to extend the LDAP person / organizationalPerson Object by one attribute (`userPrincipalName`) in order to mimic the structure of an Active Directory for testing purposes. I'm an absolute LDAP newbie using OpenLDAP via docker. Looking for the easiest way possible, it can be hackish since its not running with production data. I'm struggling hard with the manuals / articles about the topic. I stumbled upon this SO post but I have no idea about an implementation: [Extending a default schema in OpenLDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195062/extending-a-default-schema-in-openldap)

I tried adding a `user_attr.ldif` file looking like this:

```
dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema, cn=config                                    
changetype: modify                                    
add: olcAttributeTypes                                    
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.656                                    
  NAME 'userPrincipalName'                                    
  DESC 'MSDN Active Directory UPN'                                    
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch                                    
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch                                    
  SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15'                                    
  SINGLE-VALUE )
```

That seems to work when included in my `slapd-init.sh`.

Now the question is, **how to extend the person class schema to include with this defined attribute?** So far all my attempts failed unfortunately.

In the end I want to be able to add `userPrincipleName` to my user definition files which doesn't work right now `Object class violation (65); additional info: attribute 'userPrincipalName' not allowed`.

My user definition looks like so:

```
  dn: cn=Amy Wong+sn=Kroker,ou=_employees,DC=foo,DC=bar                                                                                                                  
  objectClass: top                                                                                                                              
  objectClass: person                                                                                                                       
  objectClass: organizationalPerson                                                                                                             
  objectClass: InetOrgPerson                                                                             
  cn: Amy Wong                                                                                           
  sn: Kroker                                                                                             
  memberOf: CN=some_group,OU=_Groups,DC=foo,DC=bar                     
  userPrincipalName: amy@planetexpress.com                                                               
  userPassword:: e1NTSEF9d0p2OXMyWjltMGJTMFIxV1k3QjdCRWZEVVZPQzg2Y3BWL3VDMHc9PQ==
```

Could anyone please guide me into the right direction? As said, I even take dirty shortcuts if necessary since this is for dev / testing purposes only.

best regards,
Andi

PS: Just to be precise here - I know how to modify existing records / data, I want to add an attribute to a core objectClass!